# I get an exception while using a ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I get this:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>
> Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

I get it when I try to save a List to a viewState and recover it in the  Page_PreInit event.

I set the buttons and add them to a list that I later save to a viewState:

```
ViewState["Buttons"] = buttons;
```

Then I want to retrieve them and attach them back to their eventhandlers:

```
void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<Button> btn = (List<Button>)ViewState["Buttons"];
    if (btn!=null)
    {
        foreach (var item in btn)
        {
            item.Width = 20;
            item.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
            item.CommandName = tPage.ToString();
            item.Text = tPage.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Store some value of the button in the viewstate, not the object itself and recreate it from state on the next page load.  Alternatively, the Session object can store object references just fine, and less with overhead to the client.

Comment: How do i save the state of the buttons between each postback..since all their events are gone between postbacks :(... when i press a button after a postback no eventhanlder method is triggered

Answer (score 6):

According to the exception message, `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button` isn't serializable.  (This isn't surprising.)  In order to save something to ViewState, it has to be serializable so that its complete "self" can be written to a string and stored in the `hidden` form value on the page for ViewState.

Why are you trying to store `Button`s in ViewState anyway?  ViewState is useful for storing small values and otherwise goes-in-a-hidden-form-field stuff.  But entire UI controls?  What are you trying to accomplish with that?

If you just need to dynamically create `Button` controls based on some data from ViewState, then you should just store the minimum amount of data to make that possible and create the `Button`s in the code from that data.  Something like this:

```
List<string> btn = (List<string>)ViewState["ButtonStrings"];
foreach (var str in btn)
{
    var item = new Button();
    item.Width = 20;
    item.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
    item.CommandName = tPage.ToString();
    item.Text = tPage.ToString();
    // some use of the str from the ViewState
    // or if all you need is a count, just store an int in ViewState and use a for loop
}
```

Comment: Agreed with the answer provided by @David.

Comment: I need the buttons to be re-attached with their even handling methods.. Deeper in the code, i attach the buttons programmatically to eventhandlers. But because there is a post back,the buttons dont appear, and dont have their events. Therefore, i need to re-attach their event handlers inside the prePage_init eventhandler..

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd: It sounds like your are doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd: What's the reason for doing this, though?  It sounds like you're stuck on trying to make a specific solution work, when what we need to know is the problem that you're actually trying to solve.  There's likely a much better way to approach it.

Comment: What am i doing wrong? i obtain a list of buttons,,put them in a Session state(i changed it from viewState), and retrieve in the prePage_init..How else can i reattach the buttons events..cause between the post backs.. it is all gone..all my buttons and their info :(

Comment: When a user clicks on a button marked by a page number..i want all the information of that page number to appear. However, since i produced all my page buttons programmatically, when a page number is clicked , there is a postback, the buttons lose their eventhandling methods.. in which i have a code to list all the content that the specific page represents. The result with each button press is a blank page,,cause all what was generated programmatically is gone!!!